# Does surface integral preserve the curl operation?

Tags: differential-calculus, vector-spaces, fluid-dynamics

Suppose $V\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be non-empty and at least twice differentiable (Smooth) and let $S$ be the surface that encloses $V$ (for example a sphere). Let $\textbf{F}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth vector field for all space. Let $\textbf{n}$ denote the normal to the surface $S$. Does the surface integral over $S$ preserve the curl operation with respect to the vector field $\textbf{F}$. In other words, Does the surface integral of $\textbf{n}\times\textbf{F}$ commute with the curl operation $$\textbf{curl}\biggl(\oint_{S}^{}{\textbf{n}\times\dfrac{\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}^\prime)}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}^\prime|} ~ds}\biggr) = \oint_{S}^{}{\textbf{n}\times \dfrac{ \textbf{curl} (\textbf{F}) (\textbf{r}^\prime)}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}^\prime|}~ds}?$$ Here the surface intergrals are evaluated with respect to the position $\textbf{r}^\prime$ and produce vector fields.

Comment: on the left-hand-side, the integral no longer depends on spatial variables, so how can you take the curl?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker  The notation here is the same notation used in the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#:~:text=In%20physics%20and%20mathematics%2C%20in%20the%20area%20of,known%20as%20the%20Helmholtz%20decomposition%20or%20Helmholtz%20representation. So that these integrals produce vector fields.

Comment: there is no factor $|r-r'|$ in your integrals, as in the wiki page you cite; the function $F$ depends on position, you integrate over position, how can some position dependence remain?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I just put it into $\textbf{F}$ I can rewrite it differently with that term if I need to.  I guess i should have put that. I fixed it

Comment: @MrPie : So, both surface integrals are functions of $\mathbf r$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\renewcommand\r{\mathbf r}\newcommand\n{\mathbf n}\newcommand\F{\mathbf F}\newcommand\0{\mathbf 0}\newcommand\curl{\operatorname{\mathbf{curl}}}$No. E.g., let $S$ be the unit sphere and let $\F:=(1,0,0)$, so that $\curl\F=\0$ and hence the right-hand side of the identity in question is $\0$.

On the other hand, the left-hand side of the identity in question is
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} 
\curl\oint_{S}ds(\r')\,\n(\r')\times\dfrac{\F(\r')}{|\r-\r'|}
&=\oint_{S}ds(\r')\,\curl\Big(\n(\r')\times\dfrac{\F(\r')}{|\r-\r'|}\Big), 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where the latter $\curl$ is of course with respect to $\r$.

For $\r=(1,0,0)$, the first coordinate of the latter (vector) integral (rewritten in the spherical coordinates) is
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\pi d\phi\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\, g(\phi,\theta), 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    g(\phi,\theta):=-\frac{\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi\;\sin^2\theta}
   {(2-2 \cos  \theta \sin\phi)^{3/2}} \, \sin\phi, 
\end{equation}
which is manifestly $<0$ for $(\phi,\theta)\in(0,\pi)\times(0,2\pi)$.

So, the left-hand side of the identity in question is not $\0$, and thus
the identity does not hold in general. $\quad\Box$

Comment: @losifPinelis what if $\textbf{F}$ is curl free? It seems that has an impact on this question.

Comment: @MrPie : I don't understand the point of your question. In my example, $\mathbf F$ **is** curl free.

Comment: @losifPinelis sorry I meant if $\textbf{F}$ is not curl free. The contradiction you found was easy because the right hand side vanished quickly but the left doesn't. Can you find such a field with $\textbf{Curl}(\textbf{F})\neq 0$ that still makes this a contradiction? is it true otherwise?

Comment: @MrPie : This is easy. Take your favorite non-curl-free field $\mathbf G$, and replace my curl-free $\mathbf F$ by $\mathbf F_\delta:=\mathbf F+\delta\,\mathbf G$ with a nonzero real $\delta$. Then $\mathbf F_\delta$ is not curl free, but, by continuity, your identity will still fail to hold with $\mathbf F_\delta$ in place of $\mathbf F$ if $|\delta|$ is small enough.

Comment: @losifPinelis hmmm interesting thank you!! I posted another question related to this topic if you're interested. It is here  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441022/does-arbitrary-surface-integral-in-algebraic-equation-imply-it-vanishes

Comment: @MrPie : Let us wrap it up with the current question, and then I will look at the newer one.

Comment: @Losifpinels Thanks, I think you proved the inequality is not true in general. Maybe it holds for specific type of vector fields. But this could get complicated to find which vector fields this could be (if there are any at all)

Comment: @MrPie : Your question was "Does the surface integral of $\textbf{n}\times\textbf{F}$ commute with the curl operation [...]?" This is a yes-or-no question, and it was fully answered. Your additional question concerning a non-curl-free field was answered as well. So, please let us wrap it up.

Comment: lol @losifpinelis you already wrapped it up what am I supposed to click delete or something.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different integrals. To see they are different, you could for example take $\textbf{F}(\textbf{r})=\textbf{r}$. Then the curl of $\textbf{F}$ vanishes, so the integral on the right-hand-side is zero, but the left-hand-side integral does not vanish for arbitrary $V$ (without any spherical symmetry).